# Can't add a reference to the facebook api

Tags: c#, facebook, api, reference

I click Add Reference, and add FacebookAPI.dll. Everything seems to work, i don't get any errors while writing the code, and code completion works fine.

Then, when i try to build it, it gives me an error saying it can't find the Facebook namespace, the reference is still in the reference list, but it's like i haven't added it anymore.

It works with the example included when you download the API.

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Are you using the correct .NET version? Are you running under Client Profile?

Comment: Not sure, how do I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what kind of app you're writing, but have you got "Copy Local" set to "False" on the reference properties by any chance? If so, change it to "True". Otherwise the DLL won't be copied to the output location, which is where it's required when you run the app.

EDIT: Okay, now we've got a sample solution, the problem is clear - you've either got the wrong project type or you're using the wrong DLL. The target framework in your project is ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" but you're building against the version of FacebookAPI.dll which depends on the *full* .NET 4 framework. This would have been obvious if you'd *also* told us that you'd got warnings like this (copied from trying to build it myself):

> Warning   2   The referenced assembly "FacebookAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.   faceBookTest

The solution is to *either* use the version of FacebookAPI.dll which is built for .NET 4 client profile, *or* to change the target framework version to just ".NET 4 Framework".

Comment: @BjørnMoholt: What kind of app is it? What's the *exact* error, and where are you seeing it?

Comment: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Facebook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

   i'm seeing it at the line that says `using Facebook;`

   it's a windows forms application

Comment: @BjørnMoholt: But that's a *compile-time* failure - you should be seeing it when you build, not when you run.

Comment: @BjørnMoholt: That's very strange then. Is the reference still there when you look? Have you definitely added a reference from the right project?

Comment: It's still there. I'm not sure what you mean by the right project, but it is the right dll-file, if that's what you're asking

Comment: @BjørnMoholt: Do you just have one project in your solution? Are you sure you've got the right casing in your `using` directive? (`Facebook` rather than `FaceBook` for example?)

Comment: 1 project + one form. right casing. it seems to work until i build it.

Comment: @BjørnMoholt: Can you upload the solution somewhere that we could try it ourselves? Sounds odd.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for not posting enough nfo.